# SQL : Accessing identity column value for current insertion

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity, sql-insert

```
TABLE -> Example (A,B,C,D)
```

`A` is an identity `column`. How can I do:

`INSERT INTO Example(B,C,D) VALUES (b,c, 'valueOF(A) sometext');`

I.e. I want to access the value of identity `column 'A' in column D` during insertion.
Is it possible?

Comment: Is sometext different from row to row?

Answer (score 2):

Yes with output keyword:

```
DECLARE @Result TABLE(A BIGINT)

INSERT INTO Example(B, C, D) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.A INTO @Result 
VALUES (b, c, '');
```

Now you have in `@Result` table inserted value of column `A`.

```
UPDATE e SET d = CAST(r.A as varchar(10)) + 'some text'
FROM Example e
JOIN @Result r on e.A = r.A
```

If you have `Sql Server 2012+` then you can use `sequential object`. Remove `identity` from column `A`. Then create a sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.Sequencename AS INT
MINVALUE 1
CYCLE;
```

Then use it like:

```
DECLARE @a INT    
SELECT @a = NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.Sequencename

INSERT INTO Example(A, B, C, D) 
VALUES (@a, b, c, CAST(@a as varchar(10)) + 'some text');
```

Comment: I want it while inserting itself , so the @Result  should go in place of valueOF(A).